# Impact of trim when used on mean in R

Tags: r, mean

I am executing below two statements in R

`x <- c(33,16,18,21,10,30,28)`

`mean(x, trim = 0.2)`

## The Output 22.6

My understanding is that trim should have removed `length(x) * 0.2` elements from the vector x before computing mean. That is it should removed 7*.2 = 1.4 elements.
Removing 1 element from both sides of the vector, I get 16,18,21,10,30 and hence I expect the mean to be 19 from (16+18+21+10+30)/5. Instead the O/P is 22.6

Comment: The result is equal to `mean(sort(x)[2:6])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is when `trim` goes to work it removes the highest and lowest values from the data, not the first and last values. So in your case it removes 10 and 33 and gets 22.6 as the mean of the remaining values.

Comment: Thanks John! It makes sense now.